# jetpack compose not updating icon

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

the title is updated on changes but the icon ist not.

```
@Composable
fun topBar(title: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var showMenu by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val health = remember { Health() }
    val healthMin = remember { mutableStateOf(R.drawable.music) }
    
    TopAppBar(title = {
        val location = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        SystemBroadcastReceiver(MediaPlaybackService.LOCATION_CHANGE) { intent ->
            location.value = intent!!.getStringExtra(MediaPlaybackService.LOCATION_CHANGE)!!
        }

        Text(text = location.value)
    },
        navigationIcon = {
            SystemBroadcastReceiver(Health.STATUS) { intent ->
                health.onReceive(null, intent)
                healthMin.value = health.updateLogo()
            }

            IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                Log.i("TEST","Value = ${healthMin.value}")
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(healthMin.value),
                    "contentDescription"
                )
            }
        },
...
```

I can see the changes in the log. But the UI is not updated

```
2022-02-24 12:56:24.117 3032-3032/com.example.myapplication I/TEST: Value = 2131231223
2022-02-24 12:56:24.525 3032-3032/com.example.myapplication I/TEST: Value = 2131231226
```

The SystemBroadcastReceiver is taken from the case-study [official documentaion](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#case-study-broadcastreceivers)

Comment: hard to guess without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the line `healthMin.value = health.updateLogo()` is actually called? And can you add your `SystemBroadcastReceiver` implementation?

Comment: Yes, i can confirm this via debugger and according to the logs i postet plus additional log statement in updateLogo() that are not included here. And it is the only line that changes healthMin.value. The SystemBroadcastReceiver is the one from the case-study official documentaion link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#case-study-broadcastreceivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code actually works. My problem was, that the visual icon appeared unchanged because the changed icon has only a different color. And the color is overruled by tint. So the change is not visible.

Use this if you want to see the color from the ressource and not the one from the theme.

```
Icon( painter = painterResource(healthMin.value),
      tint = Color.Unspecified,
      "contentDescription"
)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I think you wanted to comment on your original question, but instead you have posted an 'Answer'. Maybe checkout
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Yes, is was my intent because this is actually the answer to the question.